# select li when down key is press in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have **HTML** like this

```
<div class="row">
    <textarea id="txtArea" ng-model="input"
              ng-change="handleOnChange(input);getSearchField(input);"
              ng-click="search(input)" ng-focus="search(input);"
              ng-keyup="search(input)" rows="10" cols="50" tabindex="0">
    </textarea>
    <div>
        <ul ng-if="shouldSelect" id="dataList">
            <li ng-repeat="f in func | filter:searchField"
                ng-click="typeSelected(f)"> {{f}} </li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="shouldShowSubType">
            <li ng-repeat="f in selectedSubType"
                ng-click="subTypeSelected(f)"> {{f}} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now What I am trying to do is that when I press down key, I should be able to select `li` from list and when I press enter, `li` text should be added in textarea model. How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE**

I tried using below code, still it is not working.

```
 $('#txtArea').keypress(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 40)
            {
                document.getElementById("dataList").focus();
            }
        });
```

Beacuse `ul` is not getting focused. if I change `ul` to `select`, my on click functionality is not working.

Comment: When called the typeSelected() then get the current value and set it in `$scope.selecteddata`, After that in html you can use that set variable like this `{{selecteddata}}`. Have you try with this flow?

Comment: typeSelected() is called when I click on li and its working fine. My problem is that I need to select li using down key.

Answer (score -1):

You can use  `(keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown($event)` in your text area and also you can write your further logic in `onDown` function.

```
 <textarea id="txtArea" ng-model="input"
          ng-change="handleOnChange(input);getSearchField(input);"
          ng-click="search(input)" ng-focus="search(input);"
          (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown($event)" rows="10" cols="50" tabindex="0">
```

and in your **typescript file** you can do like this.

```
 onDown(event){
    console.log(event.srcElement.value);
  }
```

Comment: (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown($event)" is not working

Comment: Which version you are using of angular (angular 1 or angular 2+)?

Comment: Angular JS 1.3x